Airflow Scheduling Error it skipping one day for processing file
I have Scheduled my DAG and its getting triggered everyday at 1 am but for input file its skipping one day file instead of taking 15 date input file 14 date file is getting processed
default_args = {
    'owner': 'abc',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['abc@gmail.com'],
    'start_date': datetime.strptime("2024-07-09T12:20:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc) - timedelta(hours=5,minutes=30),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}
 
dag = DAG(
    'xyz',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='INCREMNTAL LOAD DAG',
    schedule_interval='30 19 * * *',
)

if anyone knows how to resolve this???
